# What does "total = n" in the output of "ls -l" indicate?

Tags: command-line, ls

```
ls -l

total 36

-rwxrwxr-x 1 vips vips 8776 Jan 11 20:56 a.out    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vips vips   52 Jan 11 21:44 filemk.sh    
drwxrwxr-x 2 vips vips 4096 Jan 11 22:14 hello    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vips vips 7174 Jan 11 09:23 installation.txt    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vips vips  928 Jan 11 22:26 linux_Commands    
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vips vips  142 Jan 11 20:56 prog1.c
```

What does `total` indicate?
Somewhere I read that it shows the number of blocks, but the number of blocks in my case is 
1+1+2+1+1+1 = 7 .

Then what is it?

Comment: The number you are referring to is the number of hard links for that file.

Comment: are u sure ? i have executed ls from desktop so according to your answer does that mean 36 hard links to desktop? am I guessing corrcectly or it means something else

Comment: I just looked it up in `info ls` under `What information is listed`, and it says number of hard links. I'm actually wondering myself why some of the directories in my home folder have so many hard links.

Comment: I just found https://askubuntu.com/questions/510880/why-does-directory-contain-2-hard-links, which explains that the hard link come from the subdirectories.